# ImportError: No module named job

Tags: python, mrjob

I'm trying to import mrjob so I can run a script. It was working fine about an hour ago, and then I changed some code around to try to make my job faster.

when I run this import:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "mrjob.py", line 5, in <module>
from mrjob.job import MRJob
ImportError: No module named job
```

but if I try to import in this directory (/usr/local/bin) it works. This is really starting to get to me. Anyone know how to fix this? I've tried uninstalling and installing again. Tried updating pip, tried exporting my path (even though I don't really know what I'm doing with system paths and whatnot). Anyone have any tips?

Thanks

EDIT:
It seems I can import mrjob from any directory, but the directory that my project is in. I've tried moving the project directory around but nothing seems to work. Tried updating my PATH and PYTHONPATH profile variables, nothing seems to work :/

Answer (score 0):

May be you have another module in your PYTHONPATH called mrjob?

Try this

```
import mrjob
print(mrjob.__file__)
```

to check mrjob module location.